# стоит ли использовать такую схему БД

Tags: php, mysql, база-данных, laravel

Я накидал простую схему связей таблиц ИМ, но в силу своей не опытности не могу трезво оценить её. Прошу вашего мнения, критики и рекомендаций.[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Мне кажется, у вас в каждой таблице должен быть свой уникальный id, а вы все таблицы на одну ниточку нанизываете - id продукта. В итоге и у цвета и у размера нет своих id. Если это так, то так не выйдет.

Comment: @Danny это действительно вам кажется - посмотрите на другие таблицы и увидите там ключ product_id, который вяжется на product.id

Comment: @Daniel Protopopov т.е. как я понял в общем связи правильные?

Comment: @Morpheu S да, связи правильные. Единственное, у вас похоже грамматическая ошибка в названии таблицы `product_sazes`. Думаю, вы имели ввиду `product_sizes`

Comment: Если предполагается просто ИМ "для себя", то вполне нормальная схема. Если что-то по крупнее - то я бы еще добавил таблицу languages для языковых версий сайта, а все текстовые данные из таблиц вынес бы в отдельные таблицы с привязкой к языковой таблице. В противном случае, если в дальнейшем потребуется локализация на несколько языков, будет беда)

Comment: Ну, если у вас не планируется расширение параметров продуктов (сейчас бренд, цвет и размер), то всё ок. И ок даже если планиурется, но это редко и не часто. И не много. Но если вы планируете много разных продуктов хранить в БД, каждый из которых имеет мноооого разных параметров, то при текущей схеме придутся под каждый параметр заводить таблицы, прописывать связи и т.п. Решение - убрать все таблицы харакреристик (цвет, размер и т.п.) и сделать 2 таблицы - specifications и product_specification (тут будет поля id и ещё одно - value).